# Class file not found in Maven web application in netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I'm writing a maven web application using Netbeans.

I have just started using Maven so I'm not quite sure how it works.

When I try to build the application I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project BioMarkUI: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for uk.ac.ebi.kraken.interfaces.prediction.Label not found -> [Help 1]
```

In the POM.xml I have added the following:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>uk.ac.ebi.uniprot.kraken</groupId>
        <artifactId>uniprotjapi</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <repository>
        <id>ebi-repo</id>
        <name>ebi-repo</name>
        <url>http://www.ebi.ac.uk/~maven/m2repo</url>
    </repository>
```

And in the Dependencies folder I have added the uniprotjapi jars.

When I look through the class-files indeed I can not find a class called  'uk.ac.ebi.kraken.interfaces.prediction.Label'. Where is the information that says that it has to contain this class?

Can it cause trouble that I have made up the version id '1'?(It has no version and Netbeans won't allow me to leave it blank)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last version is `2014.01`, so try this one. You cannot just make up version numbers else Maven won't be able to find it.
And make sure that you have the new repository in the right place in your POM:

```
<project>
  ...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>my-internal-site</id>
      <url>http://myserver/repo</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  ...
</project>
```

See also [Introduction to repositories](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html)

Comment: Yes, that fixed it. Thank you. :) And by the way, when I buildt my project it automatically downloaded the needed files. Is this because I added the repository-tag in the POM.xml file? (at first I didn't have it and added the dependencies manually)

Comment: That's what Maven is for :) The additional repository just indicates that you want Maven to look up missing dependencies in different repositories if they cannot be found in Maven central (which is the standard repository). If Maven finds the dependency  that you declared (via <dependency>) in one of the repositories it will download it and all other needed dependencies. Maybe you should read about more about Maven: http://www.sonatype.com/resources/books

Answer (score 0):

Wrong version, looking in http://www.ebi.ac.uk/~maven/m2repo/uk/ac/ebi/uniprot/kraken/uniprotjapi/2014.01/uniprotjapi-2014.01.pom you can see you should use version 2014.01 instead of 1 (or something else if you do not want the latest).